# Solving the system of non-linear equations in MATLAB by fsolve

Tags: matlab, function, solver

I have a code that produces a vector in MATLAB, for example the following is a three component vector (`n=3`):

```
a1_1 - sin((17*a1_1)/60 + a2_1/8 + a3_1/40 - 0.153233)
(15*a1_1)/16 + a2_1/4 + a3_1/32 - sin((17*a1_1)/60 + a2_1/8 + a3_1/40 - 0.0282326)
(3*a1_1)/4 + a2_1/2 + a3_1/8 - sin((17*a1_1)/60 + a2_1/8 + a3_1/40 + 0.846767)
```

as you can see each component is a non-linear equation. The three component of the vector forms a system of three non-linear equations having it's variables named as `a1_1`, `a1_2`and `a1_3`. I want to solve this system by `fsolve`.

How do I do that for arbitrary `n`?

Answer (score 1):

To use [`fsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html), your function must accept a vector input and return a vector of the same size. In your case you can accomplish this with an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
f = @(a)[a(1) - sin(17*a(1)/60 + a(2)/8 + a(3)/40 - 0.153233);...
         15*a(1)/16 + a(2)/4 + a(3)/32 - sin(17*a(1)/60 + a(2)/8 + a(3)/40 - 0.0282326);...
         3*a(1)/4 + a(2)/2 + a(3)/8 - sin(17*a(1)/60 + a(2)/8 + a(3)/40 + 0.846767)];
n = 3;
a0 = zeros(n,1); % Initial guess
opts = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter','TolFun',1e-8);
[a_sol,a_val,exitflag] = fsolve(f,a0,opts)
```

This returns

```
a_sol =

  -0.002818738864459
  -0.687953796565011
   9.488284986072076
```

Of course there may be more than one solution, especially for larger `n`. You can choose your initial guess to find the others. See the documentation for `fsolve` and [`optimoptions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimoptions.html) for further details on on specifying options.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the [`solve`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) command ?

> [y1,...,yN] = solve(eqns,vars) solves the system of equations eqns for the variables vars. The solutions are assigned to the variables y1,...,yN. If you do not specify the variables, solve uses symvar to find the variables to solve for. In this case, the number of variables that symvar finds is equal to the number of output arguments N.

Comment: This answer is low quality and not much more than a comment. Additionally, the OP is asking about solving the system (which might be quite large) numerically. `solve` is a symbolic math method. Due to the nature of some parameters in the equations, it's highly unlikely that `solve` will be able to obtain a symbolic solution. It will likely resort to a numerical one, in which case `fsolve` is probably a better and much faster option.